# How to include a Java library in an Android project

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, lib

I am having some problems connecting an external Java library to my Android project. I am using IntelliJ and Android Studio

For university, I have to make a Client-Server application. I have made the library so I can pass an object from the client side and save it on the server.

I can see that the library is imported in Android but I cannot access it from any class. How can fix that?

[image]

Comment: Which IDE, if any, are you using (add the appropriate tag). Explain what "imported in Android" means (edit the question).

Comment: [adding a java library to android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library) - i hope this helps.

Comment: I already have it in dependencies ' implementation files('libs/ContactsLib.jar') '

Comment: `I already have it in dependencies ' implementation files('libs/ContactsLib.jar') '` Note that this approach requires tat you have `application` plugin applied in build.script. See https://appmediation.com/how-to-add-local-libraries-to-gradle with `repositories` and  `flatDir` approach. Make also sure that you have added this `implementation` to dependencies of the correct build.gradle script.